# In Powershell -match, can $Matches be reused?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, pattern-matching, match

I'm attempting to read multiple values from a string.  The keywords may appear anywhere in the string.  I want the "Value" or content directly following it.

```
$str = 'Some version v1.2.3.4 (xyz) AnotherVal RandomKeyword: ValX'
```

I've tried

```
$test = $str -match 'Some version .*'
$val1 = $Matches[0] -replace 'Some version',''
Write-Host $val1 #gets the remainder of the string
$test2 = $val1 -match '\) '
Write-Host $Matches[0] #doesn't get the string following
```

Is there some way that `$Matches` must be reset?  Maybe there's a better pattern matching method?

Comment: so from `'Some version v1.2.3.4 (xyz) AnotherVal'` you want `v1.2.3.4` and `AnotherVal`?

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is generally the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is explicitly to write _to the display only_, thereby bypassing PowerShell's output streams and thus the ability to send the output to other commands, capture it in a variable or redirect it to a file..

Answer (score 3):

what you seem to want is capture groups. if that is the case, then this seems to do the job. [*grin*]

```
$InStuff = 'Some version v1.2.3.4 (xyz) AnotherVal'

$InStuff -match '^.+ version (.+) \(.+\) (.+)$'

$Matches
```

output ...

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              AnotherVal
1                              v1.2.3.4
0                              Some version v1.2.3.4 (xyz) AnotherVal
```

you can reach the different capture groups with the matching index number. if the type of info is known, you can use a *named* capture group.

Comment: What if the relative position (occurrence) of the "Some version" in the string is unknown.  Is there a way to just get the value that comes after? The `(.+)` part?

Comment: @nimchimpsky - without any sample data to test against, all i can give you is a wild guess ... [*grin*] ///// the regex i used put `^.+` at the start - that means `<start of string><one or more chars>`. so the regex looks like it would work on anything with `version` embedded in the string. ///// if you want some tested regex patterns, add some more samples to you OP. [*grin*]

Comment: What about the explanation regarding his use of $Matches prior to this explanation? Why in his code is $Matches[0] returning nothing?

Comment: @shadow2020 - because the OP was no longer testing against the original string ... the 2nd text was against the content of `$val1` instead of against `$str`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, your regex `Some version` starts from the beginning of the string and `.*` carries it to the end. `$matches` contains the entire string because the regex "match" is the entire string.

In your second example, `\)` covers only a close paren and a space. That's the regex "match", so that's what goes in `$matches`. To get the rest you would need to change the regex so it matches the rest as well: `$val1 -match '\) .*'`

@Lee_Dailey's answer is good for using Regex properly, but it's often *convenient* to use regex backwards and get rid of something you know, leaving the unknown left over.

```
$str = 'Some version v1.2.3.4 (xyz) AnotherVal'
$lastBit = $str -replace 'Some version '
$parts = $lastBit -split ' '
```

Comment: that is another nifty way to do it. i was tempted to go with `$Null, $Null, $Version, $Null, $OtherThing = 'Some version v1.2.3.4 (xyz) AnotherVal'.Split(' ')` - but the OP was not clear enuf when providing a specification to make that seem valid.